# Add filter "Shipped by"

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, stock

Besides **'Category', 'Material', 'Brand', 'Color', 'By price range', 'Color Group', and 'Price',** I'd like to add the filter **'Shipped by'**

This is what I have in my view:
**app/design/frontend/{my_theme}/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml**

Code:

```
                <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php $allowedfilter = Array('Category', 'Material', 'Brand', 'Color', 'By price range', 'Color Group', 'Price'); ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                    <?php if ($_filter->getItemsCount() && in_array($_filter->getName(), $allowedfilter)): ?>
                        <dt>
                            <span><?php echo str_replace(' Group', '', $this->__($_filter->getName())) ?></span>
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
                        </dd>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
```

Now, this is what I have in my filter:
**app/design/frontend/{my_theme}/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml**

Code:

```
<ol>
<?php
$brandsort = Array();
if (preg_match('/Brand/i', $this->getName())) {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load('brand', 'attribute_code');
    $option_col = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
        ->setOrder('sort_order');
    foreach ($option_col as $theoption) {
        if ($theoption['sort_order'] < 1) $theoption['sort_order'] = 999;
        $brandsort[$theoption['option_id']] = $theoption['sort_order'];
    }
}

$items = $this->getItems();

$branditems = Array();
if (preg_match('/Brand/i', $this->getName())) {
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        $items[$key]['sort_order'] = $brandsort[$item['value']];
    }
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a['sort_order'] - $b['sort_order'];
    }

    usort($items, "cmp");
}

?>
<?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
            <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
                <?php if (file_exists('skin/frontend/{my_theme}/images/colors/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $_item->getLabel())) . '.jpg') && preg_match('/Color/i', $this->getAttributeModel()->getFrontendLabel())):
                    echo '<img style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC;margin-bottom:3px !important;" src="/skin/frontend/{my_theme}/images/colors/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $_item->getLabel())) . '.jpg" alt="' . $_item->getLabel() . '" />';
                endif; ?>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
            (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I found this code that I think it does what I want, but I don't know how to integrate it to my existing code:

```
$items->joinField('manages_stock','cataloginventory/stock_item','use_config_manage_stock','product_id=entity_id','cataloginventory_stock_item.use_config_manage_stock=1 or cataloginventory_stock_item.manage_stock=1');
```

What I want is to filter products given the values of `use_config_manage_stock` and `manage_stock` i.e. products that are shipped from the stores of shipped by the manufacturer.

It doesn't have to be this way, I'm just bringing what I have so far.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your module according to this module

https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_Sale

Hope this will be helpful.